# Implement interface feature dissapeared after installing coderush for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coderush

After seeing some nice recommendations for CodeRush C# I decided to give it a try.
After installing it, loading of VS2008SP1 took way longer

But way more worse, lots of default features have disappeared
All the `ctrl +` features have gone. No more *implement interface* :(

Uninstalled it, loading times back to normal, icons still in splash screen, `ctrl +` function still broken. I'm already feeling the ants in my pants! :@

I feel more is to come. Can someone explain to me what went wrong?

Uninstall left a dll on my harddisk. Deleted it, reset my settings in visual studio. Restarted and it was back to normal. Don't know what went wrong nor what exactly fixed it.
And on that bomb shell, I'm closing this entry.

Comment: can't talk about coderush since I never used it (won't reply with an answer therefor) but I did install Resharper once. I thought it was a nightmare. Visual Studio became sooo slow... those tools just aren't for me I guess!

Comment: I too am resharper less. Mainly because it destroyed the double tab. And I'm a man who loves his double tab.

Comment: Try reset your keybindings, one of those tools pissed me off like that too in the past. I refuse to use useless training wheels!

Comment: I tried importing my old settings back (luckely exported them before) nothing happened. Tried resetting them. Again nothing. Now even the little hover square has dissapeared :(

Comment: Rather than attempting to close this question, why not leave it and allow the correct answer to float to the top so that others can benefit from this.

Answer (score 1):

Close all instances of Visual Studio & 
Try resetting VisualStudio by running "devenv /ResetSettings" from Start->Run

**REMEMBER:** Before resetting Visual Studio back up your present settings

Comment: I fixed it already: See OP. Please vote for close (man I hate how you can't just close your own question)

Answer (score 1):

Coderush installs it's own keystroke manager which sits above the IDE's keystroke selection. 
The Coderush keystroke management system is in theory more context sensitive than its VS counterpart. This means that Coderush will intercept everything but will pass the keystrokes on to VS if it's context requirements are not met.

You can view the keystrokes which Coderush has specific bindings for through the DevExpress menu..

They are available from DevExpress\Options....IDE\Shortcuts..

Also you can disable or reassign any of these which get in your way.

Could you please detail the specific Keystroke(s) you are having difficulty with?

If you would like some extended help with Coderush (And this offer is good for anyone), feel free to email me (RoryBecker@Gmail.com) and I'll do my best to help you.

I don't work for DevExpress but do have a day-job (for now :P), but if I can help then I will.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot go into details any more. I uninstalled it.

Comment: Fair enough... Given the nature of StackOverflow, I wonder whether you could have received an answer to this question within the 4 hours it was up when I answered :) If you do decide to look at it again, feel Free to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your keybindings in Visual Studio. I can't talk for CodeRush but ReSharper asks before overwriting them.

Comment: Coderush doesn't. Uninstalling removed EVERYTHING from my ctrl+.
This sucks monkey nuts...

Comment: To be clear Settings are not overwritten, but some are overridden. Coderush. This done, as per my answer, because VS Keyboard shortcuts don't allow the level of context control that DXCore shortcuts do.